# Cluster geometries that touch each other

Tags: r, geometry, sf, spatial-cluster

I'm trying to cluster the geometries in a `sf` object that touch each other. For the moment I'm using the same approach that it's explained in the answer [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/254519/group-and-union-polygons-that-share-a-border-in-r), but the problem is that the same idea doesn't work if I consider a bigger number of geometries because the touching matrix becomes too memory-heavy and I'm not using its sparse properties.

A small and (I hope) reproducible example

```r
# packages
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.6.1, GDAL 2.2.3, PROJ 4.9.3
library(osmdata)
#> Data (c) OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright

# download data
milan_primary_highways <- opq("Milan, Italy") %>%
  add_osm_feature(key = "highway", value = "primary") %>%
  osmdata_sf() %>%
  trim_osmdata(bb_poly = getbb("Milan, Italy", format_out = "polygon")[[1]]) %>%
  magrittr::use_series(osm_lines)

# Determine the non-sparse matrix of  touching geometries
touching_matrix <- st_touches(milan_primary_highways, sparse = FALSE)
#> although coordinates are longitude/latitude, st_touches assumes that they are planar

# Cluster the geometries
hc <- hclust(as.dist(!touching_matrix), method="single")

# Cut the dendrogram
groups <- cutree(hc, h=0.5)

# Results
table(groups)
#> groups
#>    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12 
#> 1444   21   18    8    4    5    8    2    3    5    2    2
plot(st_geometry(milan_primary_highways), col = groups)
```

[image]

Is there an alternative approach that takes advantage of the sparse property of the touching matrix (that I cannot use because as.dist just accepts a numeric matrix). Do you want me to provide an example when this approach does not work? The error is simply "R cannot allocate a vector of size n GB" when I use the function `hclust(as.dist(x))`.

I don't know if it's important but I tried to explain the reason why I need this clustering [here](https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/966)

Comment: Just to be clear are you saying your example given works just fine but it fails when you scale up to a larger dataset?

Comment: And also for clarity a cluster is a set of geometries that are touching, and using `h=0.5` effects that?

Comment: "Just to be clear are you saying your example given works just fine but it fails when you scale up to a larger dataset?" Yes

Comment: "And also for clarity a cluster is a set of geometries that are touching, and using h=0.5 effects that?" I set h = 0.5 since all cluster of geometries that touch each other are at distance d = 0.

Comment: having read the Q you linked to (which I answered!) I think I understand it all now!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make an adjacency *list*:

```
touching_list = st_touches(milan_primary_highways)
```

this isn't NxN so won't grow - its a list of length N where each element is only the adjacent elements. This might help it scale up to larger problems.

Now use `igraph` to create a graph objects and get the connectivity:

```
library(igraph)
g = graph.adjlist(touching_list)
c = components(g)
```

The `membership` element of `c` is of length N and says which cluster it is in. It summarises the same as your example:

```
> table(c$membership)

   1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12 
1444   21   18    8    4    5    8    2    3    5    2    2
```

So if you want to assign it to the data, do:

```
 milan_primary_highways$groups = c$membership
```

Comment: I just tried it on the complete dataset (formed by slightly more than 26000 geometries) and it works perfectly. Thank you very much.

Comment: Very nice. I would've never thought of using igraph. Beats the many lines of code that I had