# How to divide LINESTRING spatial network into equal length segments using R/sf?

Tags: r, network, sf

I'm working on a project to model car crashes within the municipality of Milan using different statistical methods. I have a big dataset of all geocoded car accidents that happenend within the municipality in 2015 and I downloaded data of the street network from OpenStreetMap using the R package `osmdata` and the following query.

```r
library(sf)
library(osmdata)
# Warning: It downloads a lot of data
geo_milan_highways <- opq("Milan, Italy", timeout = 250) %>% 
  add_osm_feature(key = "highway") %>% 
  osmdata_sf() %>% 
  # Extract LINESTRING geometries 
  magrittr::use_series("osm_lines")
```

The result is a `sf` object and every street in the municipality is mapped as one or more street segments using a LINESTRING geometry. I excluded the street segments that does not lie within the administrative boundary of the municipality and I filtered several highways since they are not relevant for this analysis (like pedestrian highway or footway).

```r
geo_milan <- getbb("Milan, Italy", format_out = "sf_polygon") %>%
  st_transform(crs = 32632) #proj: UTM WGS84 32N

library(dplyr)
geo_milan_highways <- geo_milan_highways %>%
  st_transform(crs = 32632) %>% 
  # filter highways inside the municipality of Milan
  slice(st_contains(geo_milan, .) %>% unlist()) %>%
  # Exclude some highways
  filter(
    !is.na(highway),
    !highway %in% c("motorway", "motorway_link", "trunk", "trunk_link", "pedestrian", "footway", "living_street", "service", "cycleway", "track")
  )
```

I clustered the geometries that were touching each other using the same approach described [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/310462/cluster-geometries-that-touch-each-other) to create a (sort of) highway network.

The result is a `sf` object where each LINESTRING geometry touches at least another LINESTRING geometry. The problems is that the street segments have very different lengths, from less than 1 meter to more than 3 kilometers. Is it possible to "rebuild" the network in such a way that every segment has (approximately) the same length?

I know that there are some functions to create a spatial network from a `sf` (like `SpatialLinesNetwork` of `dodgr` package) but I don't know how to use it to "refactor" the network with segments of the same length. There is also a function named `st_linesubstring` of the `lwgeom` package with an [example](https://gist.github.com/dblodgett-usgs/cf87392c02d73f1b7d16153d2b66a8f3) on how to divide a LINESTRING into LINESTRINGS but it does not consider the neighbouring segments of the spatial network.

Comment: What length do you want to divide the lines into? And why? If there really is a 1m "street" (seems ridiculous but maybe 3 or 4m is more believable) do you want everything divided into 1m sections? Because you can't go any larger than your smallest segment if you want everything in equal seqments. What are you doing this for?

Comment: _What length do you want to divide the lines into? And why?_ I think that a reasonable approach is to "refactor" (probably "divide" is not the right verb here) the sf object into LINESTRINGS whose length is equal to 100/150 meters. I need this refactoring since I want to apply a Poisson regression (or something similar) to model the number of car crashes happening on each road segment. At the moment I consider the street length simply as an offset of the poisson regression but it would be better to have equally sized segments.

Comment: _If there really is a 1m "street" (seems ridiculous but maybe 3 or 4m is more believable) do you want everything divided into 1m sections? Because you can't go any larger than your smallest segment if you want everything in equal seqments. What are you doing this for?_ The 1m "street" is not really a street but it's only a segment that composes a part of a street. I used the wrong verb ("divide") in the title of this question but what I mean is a procedure like the following comment:

Comment: 1) set a threshold for a segment length (i.e. 150m); 2a) if a street segment is shorter than the threshold then it should be aggregated with another segment it's touching; 2b) if a segment is too long then it should be split into segments whose length is approximately equal to the threshold length; 3) the process should be repeated until all LINESTRING objects have a length approximately equal to the threshold.

Answer (score -1):

there is a blog about dividing street segments into equal distances, you can check it. [blog](https://ywu120766.medium.com/how-to-divide-linestring-sf-into-equal-segments-with-r-935a9ebaec7a)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/256804)

Comment: Thank you for your reminder. Below is more detail about this link: The main idea is to move the coordinates on a LINESTRING to generate a new LINESTRING with 100 intervals. The answer in the link can be divided into any length you want, for example, 100m, 150, 135m ,or other lengths.

Comment: Please do not comment on your own Answer. Instead use the `edit` button below the answer to edit it.